# TSQL: Datetime overlapping and interval values

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Need help to create a query for this.

```
Start               | End
2009-01-01 06:00:00 | 2009-01-01 14:00:00
2009-01-01 06:00:00 | 2009-01-02 06:00:00
2009-01-02 07:00:00 | 2009-01-02 08:00:00
2009-01-03 06:00:00 | 2009-01-03 14:00:00
2009-01-03 09:00:00 | 2009-01-03 11:00:00
2009-01-04 22:00:00 | 2009-01-05 06:00:00
2009-01-05 01:00:00 | 2009-01-05 10:00:00
```

I would like to get un-overlapped time for interval (`2009-01-01 00:00:00` - `2009-01-31 00:00:00`)
with sum for each day like this:

```
Date       | Duration
2009-01-01 | 18
2009-01-02 | 7
2009-01-03 | 8
2009-01-04 | 2
2009-01-05 | 10
```

Then looking for the total sum per whole requested interval.

Are you able to help construct this query?

Comment: Will the requested interval always start and stop at midnight of the respective days?

Comment: What is the name of your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH Times AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT(Start) AS Time FROM intervals
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT([End]) AS Time FROM intervals),
     Days AS (SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Time)) AS Time FROM Times),
     Times2 AS (
        SELECT Time FROM times
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Time FROM days),
     Times3 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Time) AS rn, Time FROM Times2),
     Times4 AS (
        SELECT T1.Time AS Start, T2.Time AS [End]
        FROM Times3 T1
        JOIN Times3 T2
        ON T1.rn + 1 = T2.rn),
     IntervalParts AS (
         SELECT DISTINCT Times4.*
         FROM Times4
         JOIN intervals
         ON Times4.Start >= intervals.Start AND Times4.[End] <= intervals.[End]),
     IntervalsByDay AS (
         SELECT 
             DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Start)) AS Day,
             DATEDIFF(hh, Start, [End]) AS Duration 
         FROM IntervalParts)
SELECT Day, SUM(Duration) AS Duration
FROM IntervalsByDay
GROUP BY Day
```

Results:

```
Day                     Duration 
2009-01-01 00:00:00.000 18
2009-01-02 00:00:00.000 7
2009-01-03 00:00:00.000 8
2009-01-04 00:00:00.000 2
2009-01-05 00:00:00.000 10
```

To restrict it to a certain range, just add an appropriate WHERE clause.

Comment: Created tmp table @intervals and put @ in the query, but got "Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 36
Must declare the scalar variable "@intervals"."
In line: " ON Times4.Start >= intervals.Start AND Times4.[End] <= intervals.[End]),"
Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: I don't understand why you are using temp tables. It seems entirely unnecessary. Isn't your data in a real table?

Comment: Temp is just for testing. Will try on real table. Temp table name is @intervals.

Comment: Notice that in my query you have to change the table name to your real table name in many places, otherwise you will get errors. If you had put the name of your table in your question, I could have done that for you in the first place, saving you some work and reducing the possibility of you making errors. Please remember to include the table name next time you ask a question.

Comment: Sorry for table name, this is my first question on this page. For the example table it works. What is the diference if I use temp table and if interval is bigger than 1 day difference (2009-01-07 06:00:00 | 2009-01-10 14:00:00)?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258269%28SQL.80%29.aspx) in sqlserver. I'm not sure what db server you're using, but I imagine other RDBMS's would have something similar or enough that you could create your own function to do this.

```
SELECT start, DATEDIFF(hh, start, end) FROM ......
```

It looks like I missed a multiple dates portion of this. To split this by days, I think you'd almost have to process each record separately and store in a temp table or something. Maybe you could create a function that returns a table for each record that splits the durations by date and then this could be SUMMED for each date.?